# Ruby MongoDB Driver Client Side Query Matcher

Tags: javascript, c, ruby, mongodb

I'm building a system in Ruby using WebSockets that will notify JS clients of changes to collections that are applicable to the models & collections the JS client is viewing. I would like to have the JS client periodically send registration messages to the WebSocket telling it what models it is currently viewing, and also the collections (or collection subset specified by query).

So in order to make this work, the API hosting the WebSocket server will need to test if a query matches a document that has been updated/created. I would like to do this without sending a query to Mongo, and I found a solution in the C driver that would work on the (mongo) client side: http://api.mongodb.org/c/current/mongoc_matcher_new.html
http://api.mongodb.org/c/current/matcher.html

Unfortunately I didn't see a way of calling this method through the Ruby drivers. Any clue how I might be able to use the mongoc_matcher_new function in Ruby? Or does anyone have a better suggestion to improve the architecture of this solution to only send applicable updates to JS clients?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually used FFI to run the code I needed:

```
MongoC.test_query_match(document_string, json_query_string)
```

C code:

```
#include <bcon.h>
#include <mongoc.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int test_query_match(char *document, char *query) {
    mongoc_matcher_t *matcher;
    bson_t *d;
    bson_t *q;

    bson_error_t doc_parse_error;
    bson_error_t query_parse_error;
    bson_error_t matcher_error;

    d = bson_new_from_json(document, strlen(document), &doc_parse_error);
    q = bson_new_from_json(query, strlen(query), &query_parse_error); 

    matcher = mongoc_matcher_new(q, &matcher_error);
    if ( !matcher ) {
        bson_destroy(q);
        bson_destroy(d);
        return 0;
    }

    int match = mongoc_matcher_match(matcher, d);

    bson_destroy(q);
    bson_destroy(d);
    mongoc_matcher_destroy(matcher);

    return match;
}
```

The Ruby FFI code:

```
require 'ffi'

module MongoC

  extend FFI::Library

  ffi_lib 'c'
  ffi_lib File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/mongoc/mongoc.so'

  attach_function :test_query_match, [:string, :string], :int

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you're going to be able to do it without querying back to Mongo. The standard way of doing this is by tailing the oplog, but the oplog is only going to give you the database/collection and the _id. So I don't think you would be able to support an arbitrary query with just the oplog, you would need to fetch the document in order to determine a match.

I would suggest that you take a look at how [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/) does this. This [blog post](https://www.meteor.com/blog/2013/12/17/meteor-070-scalable-database-queries-using-mongodb-oplog-instead-of-poll-and-diff) gives an overview of their approach. There is also a [wiki page](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Oplog-Observe-Driver) with more specifics on [OplogObserveDriver](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/cf4477ff27cba9f8a8f63ec2f435969af0b6707c/packages/mongo/oplog_observe_driver.js).